# How do I send mail from my ruby on rails application?

Tags: email, ruby, mail-server

How do i send mail on my ubuntu system. I need to send mail in my ruby on rails application but can't test, because mail isn't being sent. What do i need to do on my system. (now testing this app is making me realize why mail wasn't being sent through that Evolution thing i have installed)

Answer (score 0):

The Evolution thing is an MUA (Mail User Agent) like Outlook, Thunderbird, or any number of programs intended for user to read and create email messages.  Your program is also a limited MUA (likely creation only).

You need to send your e-mail to an MTA (Mail Transfer Agent).  If you configure the return address correctly, you may be able to use the same MTA that you connect to with Evolution.  In this case the SMTP server used to send email.  If you are using one of the e-mail libraries you should be able to specify the SMTP server name as well as a user-id and password if required.

Many packages require an MTA so you may have Postfix, Exim4, or Sendmail already installed.  Check for programs listening on port 25.  If so you can use localhost as your SMTP server.  If you need to send email other systems you may need to configure your MTA as a satellite to your ISPs server which will relay your message out to the Internet.